# Understanding the use of BigInt

Tags: julia, bigint

I'm struggling to understand how to use `BigInt` correctly. It seems to me that one should use `BigInt` when `Int64` or `Int128` is not enough, and apparently `BigInt` uses arbitrary precision arithmetic (of which I have no knowledge of).

Let's say I want to compute the factorial of some big number, e.g. 30. I don't know how many bits is required to store `factorial(30)` but both

```
test = Int128
test = factorial(30)
```

and

```
test = BigInt
test = factorial(30)
```

produces `-8764578968847253504` which is obviously incorrect.

According to the Julia lang documentation, it seems that the usual mathematical operators are defined for this type (BigInt), and the results are promoted to a `BigInt`. Therefore I fail to see what I'm doing wrong, I have obviously misunderstood something. Hoping some of you might have an explanation for me :)

PS: I'm running the 64-bit version of Windows 7 if that has anything to say

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`factorial` will calculate a result with the same type as its argument, so

```
test = factorial(BigInt(30))
```

Will work, will be using a `BigInt` throughout computation.

```
test = BigInt(factorial(30))
```

Won't work, will convert the already overflowed Int result into a BigInt.

```
test = BigInt(factorial(BigInt(30)))
```

Will work, but the outer BigInt is redundant, as the result is already a BigInt.

The code you wrote

```
test = BigInt
test = factorial(30)
```

is essentially meaningless. You said

> According to the Julia lang documentation, it seems that the usual
>   mathematical operators are defined for this type (BigInt), and the
>   results are promoted to a BigInt.

so I'm guessing you thought this meant "the result should be a BigInt", but it doesn't. It assigns the type `BigInt` to a variable test, then calculates `factorial` on the `Int` literal 30. It then stores it in `test`, squashing the previous value, which was `BigInt`. Maybe check out the Types section of manual. Julia doesn't automatically promote `Ints` to `BigInts` on overflow - you need to start with a `BigInt`. This is for performance (and other) reasons.

Most operations are defined on `BigInt`s - only some linear algebra operations (like eigenvalues) might not be. Just change your number into a `BigInt` once and it will propagate throughout the computation. Most people will never need `BigInt`s - tend to only crop up in a research setting. `Int` (which is the same as the platform integer size, so `Int64` on your computer), goes pretty big - and is fast.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, makes sense, will stick to explicit casting when dealing with `BigInts` from hereon out :)

Answer (score 2):

I want to prefix this answer with the assertion that I do not know anything about Julia, but reading the documentation at https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#Arbitrary-Precision-Arithmetic-1 it can be seen that they use `factorial(BigInt(40))`, so the explicit cast seems to be required.

Try `factorial(BigInt(30))` to see if that gives the expected result.

Also, from that page:

> However, type promotion between the primitive types above and
>   BigInt/BigFloat is not automatic and must be explicitly stated.

So I would try 3 things, to see what works:

```
test = factorial(BigInt(30))
test = BigInt(factorial(30))
test = BigInt(factorial(BigInt(30)))
```

Comment: Thanks that. worked. That actually makes a lot of sense since most functions in Julia are polymorphic (I think I'm using polymorphic correctly here), so when `factorial` is getting a `BigInt` type it will also return a `BigInt` type, in contrast to what I first did, which was feeding it an `Int` type

Comment: To clarify, explicit casting worked, the first example in your list worked perfectly, have not tried the other ones

Comment: Just to note that in Julia, if I understand correctly, `BigInt(30)` is not casting, nor is it a conversion or promotion (though those operations are a possible in Julia).  You are actually calling a constructor.  [The manual](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#arbitrary-precision-arithmetic) explains this and a lot more detail as well.

Answer (score 2):

Related question about arbitrary precision math. Note I have only spent two days experimenting with the Julia language. After viewing this posting I added the BigInt casting which got one more number printed out. I must be missing something as it still does not execute like it is using arbitrary precision for all the calculations that it needs to. I also had to add the try/catch as the ismersenneprime function throws an error if it is not a Merseene prime number. According to the documentation I thought it was supposed to return true or false.

```
# Perfect numbers are 2^(p-1)x(2^p-1) if 2^p-1 is Mersenne prime.
using Compat
using Primes

limit = 1000000

for p = 1:limit
  perfect = BigInt(2^(p-1))*(BigInt(2^p)-1)
  try 
    if ismersenneprime(BigInt(2^p)-1)
      println("$p $perfect")
    end
  catch e
#   println(e)
  end
end

2 6
3 28
5 496
7 8128
13 33550336
17 8589869056
19 137438691328
31 2305843008139952128
61 2658455991569831744654692615953842176
```

Comment: I guess I have also not mastered posting here as it has totally obliterated the formatting. I is it possible to just use HTML tags in the future; like <pre> </pre>?

Comment: I finally got it to work by redefining limit as limit = BigInt(typemax(Int128)) + 1